# How to create a hover animation with product.images in rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I attempt to create a simple hover effect for images powered with <%= image_tag %> in Rails.
I've seen a lot of resources but I didn't find any solution working with object.images. Maybe JavaScript is the best option ?

Here's my code :

```
<%= image_tag product.image, class: "show-prdct", mouseover: product.image_pres1 %>
```

How could I replace product.image by product.image_pres1 on hover ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was quite easy, for Rails 4 app :

```
<%= image_tag product.image, 
        onMouseover: "this.src='#{image_path(product.image_pres1)}'", 
        onMouseout: "this.src='#{image_path(product.image)}'" %>
```